# initiate bitset with an integer declared in my function in c++

Tags: c++, bitset

I want to do

```
    int count=32;
    bitset<count>(a);
```

I have not put my entire code as it was irrelevant the basic thing is that I have to create a bitset of a given length and that length is calculated in the program. But this throws an error showing count cannot appear in a constant expression. What would be the solution to this.

Comment: The N in `std::bitset<N>` must be constant. If you need variable-sized bitsets you should look elsewhere.

Comment: Template parameters have to be available at compile time.

Comment: The template parameter should be a compile time constant for `std::bitset`

Comment: @barmar is there any way to do this using bitset if not what alternative would you suggest

Comment: Use a vector of bits instead of a bitset?

Comment: You can use [_`dynamic_bitset`_](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html)